# Express $\frac{1}{2n + 1}\,,\,n\in\mathbb{N}$ as a series of the form $\sum_{m = 0}^\infty\frac{a_m n!}{(n + m)!}\,.$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, factorial

I'm interested in performing a sum, and as part of my summation, I need to express
$$
\frac{1}{2n + 1}\,,\,n\in\mathbb{N}\,,
$$
as a series of the form
$$
\sum_{m = 0}^\infty\frac{a_m n!}{(n + m)!}\,.
$$
I believe that such a feat should be possible, although I have no idea where to start! Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Edit:
To clarify notation, one could have expanded as a power series:
$$
\frac{1}{2n + 1} = -\sum_{m = 1}^\infty a_m\frac{1}{n^m}
$$
with $a_m = (-2)^{-m}$, although this is not of the desired form. That is to say, $a_m$ must depend *only* on the integer $m$, and not $n$.

Edit 2:
I'll also add that one can check by hand that the first several terms are
$$ a_0 = 0 $$
$$ a_1 = \frac12 $$
$$ a_2 = \frac14 $$
$$ a_3 = \frac{3}{8} $$
$$ a_4 = \frac{15}{16} $$
$$ a_5 = \frac{105}{32} $$

This appears to satisfy the pattern
$$
a_m = \frac{(2m-3)!!}{2^m}
$$
for $m\geq 1$. It's a little annoying to see that these terms grow without bound, but perhaps my ask is simply too much!

Comment: This needs more detail  Are there any restrictions on the $a_m$?  You could of course just take $a_0=\frac 1{2n+1}$ and $a_m=0$ for $m>0$ if you wanted.

Comment: a is a function of m (hence the subscript)

Comment: Yes...my $a_m$ vary with $m$ (though not by much, I agree).  What I wrote is clearly of the form you indicated.  If you wanted some restrictions on the $a_m$, you should indicate them.

Comment: $a_m$ must depend only on the integer $m$, not the integer $n$.

Comment: So, that would be a good thing to add to your post then.

Comment: In equivalent terms you are looking for a binomial transform: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_transform

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio oh this is great! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $(a_m)_{m\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a solution. Taking $n\to\infty$ (which can be done termwise), we get $a_0=0$. For $|x|<1$ the series $f(x)=\sum_{m=0}^\infty a_{m+1}x^m/m!$ converges, and we have $$\frac1{2n+1}=\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{a_{m+1}n!}{(n+m+1)!}=\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{a_{m+1}}{m!}\int_0^1 x^m(1-x)^n\,dx=\int_0^1 (1-x)^n f(x)\,dx.$$ This has at most one solution $f\in L^2$ (by the density argument: the difference of any two solutions is orthogonal to each polynomial in $x$), and clearly $$f(x)=\frac1{2\sqrt{1-x}}=\frac12\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{(2m-1)!!}{(2m)!!}x^m$$ (here $0!!=(-1)!!=1$) *is* a solution. This gives the expression for $a_m$ you found.